# C, perform operation on array elements based on an expression

Tags: c, arrays

I am looking for a function equivalent to fortrans "WHERE", for C. I have a big array of numbers and i need to perform an operation on the elements that have a property based on an expression. An example in fortran is

```
WHERE(ABS(array).LE.1e-10)
            array = 0.0d0
ENDWHERE
```

Is there any way to perform this in C without the use of loops?

Comment: @ser159536 In the both languages there is used a loop either implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin missing a `++`

Comment: You can disguise the loop (for example as a recursion), but you can't avoid a loop to do an operation over an array in C.

Comment: A loop is clearly the right way to go.  Something like `for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {if fabs(arr[i]) <= 1e-10) arr[i] = 0.0;}`

Comment: @PaulHankin - only consideration with a recursive solution is if it is a really "big array of numbers", then StackOverflow is a possibility when stack space is exhausted.

Comment: I see, just as i thought. What would be a proper recursive solution? Since my array could be millions of entries.

Comment: @user159536 I think you have it backwards.  If the array is large, the last thing you should do is recurse.  A loop won't use any memory.  Use a loop.  Recursing will be slower and use way way way more memory.  Well, unless it tail recurses *and* the compiler transforms it for you.  But it still makes no sense to write it that way.

Comment: @TomKarzes Ah i see, so a normal for will suffice. Thank you for the info!